# Grunt process breaks at certain point generator-angular-fullstack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

Can someone please help me explain what that does. The grunt process produces errors. I need to find out why. What does the "src" do?

```
imagemin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
      src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
    }]
  }
},
```

///// EDIT ///// Actual Output

Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task
    Total saved: 0 B

```
Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2014-07-12 09:39:26 UTC)
loading tasks  78ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 59%
svgmin:dist    54ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 41%
Total 132ms
    Warning: Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Warning: Command failed:  Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-07-12 09:39:26 UTC)
loading tasks  188ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 62%
imagemin:dist  113ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 37%
Total 302ms Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

///// EDIT 2 //////
With the command "grunt imagemin --verbose --force" I get the following error:

```
Files: client/assets/images/timeline/jd_small.png -> dist/public/assets/images/timeline/jd_small.png
Options: interlaced, optimizationLevel=3, progressive
Warning: Command failed:  Used --force, continuing.
Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined
```

Not sure what that tells me though.

Comment: Would it be possible to post the errors in question (as well as the command which produced the errors)?

Comment: Looks like this configuration has to do with the grunt [imagemin plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) - might help to read the docs on that site?

Comment: I think it might has to do with the pattern in the src? I'm not too familiar with the regex like stuff...

Comment: the src parameter defines the files to match. Though it looks similar, it's not actually a regular expression. It's a glob (like used in a shell to match multiple files - i.e. "*.txt". See http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns for more details. I'm afraid I'm not too familiar with the syntax so I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

Comment: Would probably be useful to run grunt with the --verbose or --debug option - might yield some more useful messages?

Comment: Does adding the `cache: false` option work?

Comment: where do I have to add it exactly? before the dist? I'm sure it has to do something with the subfolders, because when i remove them the error doesn't appear

Comment: @Tino in the [imagemin options like so](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/commit/3e435fa74b1574223f129867621a9a800cea2af9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turned out that grunt throws an error if the image is corrupt. I opened it in Photoshop saved it and voila grunt worked.

Would be cool if grunt was able to output an error like that....

Comment: Perhaps submit an issue to [the imagemin project](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin)?